# Unique constraint on nested one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I'm trying to represent three types of things -- grandparent, parents, and children. There's a one-to-many relationship between grandparents and parents, and a one-to-many relationship between parents and children. Parents that share a grandparent must have a unique name. *The same goes for children, as all children that share a grandparent must have a unique name.*

Here's an example schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE grandparent (
  grandparentid TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  uniquefield1 TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE parent (
  parentid TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  grandparentid TEXT REFERENCES grandparent,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  uniquefield2 TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (grandparentid, name)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  childid TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  grandparentid TEXT REFERENCES grandparent,
  parentid TEXT REFERENCES parent,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  uniquefield3 TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (grandparentid, name)
);
```

I'm trying to come up with something that removes the need for the `grandparentid` field in the `child` table, because I don't want to get into a situation where it disagrees with the contents of the `parentid` field. However, I can't just remove it (to the best of my knowledge) because I still need a unique constraint on the pair of `grandparentid` and `name`.

Also worth noting is that each generation has unique information. It's a bit of a contrived example, because the actual use case is domain-specific and would just obfuscate the problem.

Comment: Just remove it.  You can access it through the parent.  Just an extra `join`.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I still won't be able to ensure that a child's name is unique across the grandparent ID.

Comment: I'd store all generations in the same table. With a mother and a father column, both fk's.

Comment: Unfortunately, each table actually does represent different things so I can't fit them all in the same table. Sorry for not including that in the original question, I've amended it to reflect that.

Comment: Do you mean most/many people will be stored in several tables? With different id's. Very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to avoid the redundancy that is not controlled by the database but by your app. A single bug in your app can store discrepancies in the data that it would be hard to resolve. Redundancy is OK if it's properly controlled.

You need to include the `grandparentid` column in the `child` table to ensure uniqueness of the name column in the subset. Now, the key aspect to consider is that you need a **composite key** in the `parent` table that can be referenced from the `child` table. This way you will be able to enforce the uniqueness in the `child` table and make sure the redundancy is always validated by the database.

For example:

```
create table grandparent (
  grandparentid text primary key,
  uniquefield1 text not null
);

create table parent (
  parentid text not null,
  grandparentid text not null references grandparent (grandparentid),
  name text not null,
  uniquefield2 text not null,
  unique (parentid, grandparentid), -- added this key
  unique (grandparentid, name)
);

create table child (
  childid text primary key,
  grandparentid text not null,
  parentid text not null,
  name text not null,
  uniquefield3 text not null,
  unique (grandparentid, name),
  foreign key (parentid, grandparentid) 
    references parent (parentid, grandparentid)
);
```

Pay attention to the last line:

```
  foreign key (parentid, grandparentid) 
     references parent (parentid, grandparentid)
```

This foreign key references a unique constraint in the `parent` table.

Using this structure you won't be able to insert a wrong combination of `grandparentid` and `parentid`. The database just won't have it.

Comment: In `parent` table, what is the *primary* key? The single `parentid` or the new composite key? (Composite primary key has several disadvantages, especially if you use ORM)

Comment: @IstvánBékési In the example the parent table does not have a primary key. I can be added as needed. On the other hand I don't see any disadvantage for composite keys in ORMs. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The use of composite primary keys is generally discouraged in ORM best practices due to the added complexity and potential for performance issues that they can introduce. Simple primary keys are more efficient, easier to work with, and are less prone to error. An example from [doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/best-practices.html#avoid-composite-keys)

Comment: @IstvánBékési Disclaimer: I have participated in the development of an ORM. I cannot think of a performance penalty for composite keys. That may be a constraint affecting green ORMs, but it don't think it applies to mature ones.

Comment: In JPA (and in ORMs in general) every entity must have a primary key. Your original answer confused me a bit, because you removed the primary key from `parent.parentid` and the commented note `--added this key` suggested me that it is necessary to change the primary key to a composite. I recommend to keep `parentid` as the single primary key according to the original example, because it is m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶e̶f̶f̶i̶c̶i̶e̶n̶t̶, easier to work with and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure integrity using a *composite foreign key*.

```
CREATE TABLE grandparents (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE parents (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  grandparent_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (id, grandparent_id),
  UNIQUE KEY (grandparent_id, name),
  FOREIGN KEY (grandparent_id) REFERENCES grandparents(id)
);

CREATE TABLE children (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  grandparent_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (grandparent_id, name),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id, grandparent_id) REFERENCES parents(id, grandparent_id)
);
```

Check this [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zJdMkGF4fmAiprU5DwnVS/0)